# create method creating 2 records instead of one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I click on link "Add friend", 2 identical records are made. Only one record should have been created. I've tried different ways of linking to the `create` method as it may be the underlying issue.

View: users/index

```
<ul>
  New friend requests
  <% @incoming.each do |user| %>
  <% @users.each do |f| %>
  <% if f.id == user.user.id %>
  <li>
    <%= f.name %>
    <%= link_to "Accept request", friend_request_path(id: user), :method => :put %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<ul>
    All users
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
  <li><%= user.name %>
   <%= link_to "Add Friend", friend_requests_path(:friend_id => user), :method => :post %></li>
   <% end %>
   <% end %>

 </ul>
```

controller:

```
class FriendRequestsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_friend_request, except: [:index, :create]

    def index
        @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
        @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
    end

    def create
        friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
        @friend_request = current_user.friend_requests.new(friend: friend)

        if @friend_request.save
            flash[:notice]="Friend request sent."
            redirect_to users_path
        else
            flash[:alert]="Friend request not sent."
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def update
        @friend_request.accept
        flash[:notice]="Friend added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def destroy
        @friend_request.destroy
        head :no_content
    end


    private

    def set_friend_request
        @friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

logs:

```
Started POST "/friend_requests?friend_id=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-13 23:55:26 -0500
Processing by FriendRequestsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+bCpezt22p+Jt3fmdbb66tIUrSJgsyfTpLbY2WHsZo9DAfwV+hxEr6GRU7nwESTPX6Oqz56GuikiG+qhjFhVcQ==", "friend_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
Started POST "/friend_requests?friend_id=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-13 23:55:26 -0500
Processing by FriendRequestsController#create as HTML
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "friend_requests" ("user_id", "friend_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["friend_id", 2], ["created_at", "2017-12-14 04:55:26.660451"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-14 04:55:26.660451"]]
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+bCpezt22p+Jt3fmdbb66tIUrSJgsyfTpLbY2WHsZo9DAfwV+hxEr6GRU7nwESTPX6Oqz56GuikiG+qhjFhVcQ==", "friend_id"=>"2"}
   (8.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 64ms (ActiveRecord: 14.3ms)


  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (2.8ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.8ms)  INSERT INTO "friend_requests" ("user_id", "friend_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["friend_id", 2], ["created_at", "2017-12-14 04:55:26.698180"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-14 04:55:26.698180"]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 18.7ms)
```

Comment: `create` method is not the source of issue. But the request to `create` action is going twice.

Comment: If that was a hint I need another one. I don't see how my link_to could possibly be sending two requests??

Comment: The `link_to xxx, method: :post` processed by jQuery, so something went wrong with your jQuery code.

Comment: Does it happen every time you click the "Add Friend" link?

Comment: Yes every time I click the link two records are made. The only JQuery I have in the app is the drop down in the header that I would think would be unrelated.

Comment: so far as i see your method type is `put` that means its going to `update` action and you are sending `friend_id` with `Add Friend` and your are getting `@friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:id])` which should be  `@friend_request = FriendRequest.find(params[:friend_id])` and i think something went wrong with `accept` method . can you share your `accept` method?

Comment: def accept
     user.friends << friend
     destroy
    end

Comment: https://github.com/jmooree30/jakebook link is current

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one guys if anyone came up with anything..

Answer (score 1):

JS was being loaded twice into my application. Removing these lines from my application.js file resulted in only one request being made.

Removed:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require rails-ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Current:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
```

Comment: thanks for this! the jquery-ujs JS was causing mine to duplicate records.